# Laravel vapor deploy omits manifest file from upload

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

I have an `Laravel` app  `Vue` spa, project which contains two applications in one (residents, suppliers). These apps are under different subdomains (pro / my).

On deployment of my project using `vapor`, it completes successfully but it ignores uploading both my manifest files.

Here's the log output of the last deploy:

```
==> Uploading Asset: css/app.css (202.58KB)
==> Uploading Asset: css/app.css.map (88.46KB)
==> Uploading Asset: js/my.js (80677.13KB)
==> Uploading Asset: js/my.js.LICENSE.txt (8.15KB)
==> Uploading Asset: js/my.js.map (32497.13KB)
==> Uploading Asset: js/popper.js (52.06KB)
==> Uploading Asset: js/pro.js (80672.56KB)
==> Uploading Asset: js/pro.js.LICENSE.txt (8.15KB)
==> Uploading Asset: js/pro.js.map (32491.59KB)
==> Uploading Asset: my-sw.js (20.28KB)
==> Uploading Asset: my-sw.js.map (7.86KB)
==> Uploading Asset: pro-sw.js (20.3KB)
==> Uploading Asset: pro-sw.js.map (7.86KB)
==> Uploading Asset: safari-pinned-tab.svg (14.91KB)
==> Copying Unchanged Asset: android-chrome-192x192.png (13.9KB)
==> Copying Unchanged Asset: android-chrome-512x512.png (45.11KB)
==> Copying Unchanged Asset: apple-touch-icon.png (7.33KB)
==> Copying Unchanged Asset: favicon-16x16.png (1.11KB)
==> Copying Unchanged Asset: favicon-32x32.png (1.53KB)
==> Copying Unchanged Asset: favicon.ico (14.73KB)
==> Copying Unchanged Asset: js/popper.js.map (48.71KB)
==> Copying Unchanged Asset: mstile-150x150.png (6.9KB)
==> Copying Unchanged Asset: sql-wasm.wasm (1082.35KB)
```

But in the `config.vapor` we list the following files to serve:

```
'serve_assets' => [
    'android-chrome-192x192.png',
    'android-chrome-512x512.png',
    'apple-touch-icon.png',
    'favicon.ico',
    'favicon-16x16.png',
    'favicon-32x32.png',
    'mix-manifest.json',
    'mstile-150x150.png',
    'my-manifest.json',
    'pro-manifest.json',
    'safari-pinned-tab.svg',
    'my-sw.js',
    'pro-sw.js',
],
```

We upload manually the manifests and it all works. Is there a reason is vapor ignoring these that I have missed?